# RegionFunction is imprecise

Tags: graphics, precision-and-accuracy, regions

I've managed to print clipping a figure inside another.  That's impossible out of controlling directly their coordinates (x, y[, z]), and then it's impossible to do a graphic clipping over an already generated graphic.  But after this many steps to see all of these, I find the `RegionFunction` you need for xy clipping, is not precise.  Where is it the problem here

```
ContourPlot[{
  x^2 + y^2 == 1,
  (x - Cos[2 Pi 1/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 1/6])^2 == 1,
  (x - Cos[2 Pi 2/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 2/6])^2 == 1,
  (x - Cos[2 Pi 3/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 3/6])^2 == 1,
  (x - Cos[2 Pi 4/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 4/6])^2 == 1,
  (x - Cos[2 Pi 5/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 5/6])^2 == 1,
  (x - Cos[2 Pi 6/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 6/6])^2 == 1
  },
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Increase [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html).

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 
   1, (x - Cos[2 Pi 1/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 1/6])^2 == 
   1, (x - Cos[2 Pi 2/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 2/6])^2 == 
   1, (x - Cos[2 Pi 3/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 3/6])^2 == 
   1, (x - Cos[2 Pi 4/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 4/6])^2 == 
   1, (x - Cos[2 Pi 5/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 5/6])^2 == 
   1, (x - Cos[2 Pi 6/6])^2 + (y - Sin[2 Pi 6/6])^2 == 1}, {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should have imagined.

Answer (score 4):

Or only use `Circle`.

```
Graphics[{MapIndexed[{Thick, ColorData[97][1 + First@#2], 
     Circle[#, 1]} &, CirclePoints[6]], White, Annulus[{1, 2}], 
  ColorData[97][1], Circle[]}, PlotRange -> 1.1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive.  I'd like to have that command of Mma.  But, anyway, still missing something as simple as ClipGraphics with a region